# I'm not sure how "favourite" is used

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Her position as **favourite** to top first-round voting will turn the campaign into a race to face her in the run-off. (Source: [This Link](http://www.theworldin.com/edition/2017/article/12593/fight-france))

Does this mean she is very likely to be in top first-found voting?

Comment: have you tried looking in a good dictionary. for example this one? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/favourite Note definition 1.1 for the noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean she is very likely to be in top first-found voting?

**No.** It means she is widely expected (not always the same as actually likely) to be the very top (not among the top) in the first round (not found) of voting.